# Добавление SSL Locations в Charles

Tags: android, proxy, эмулятор

Здравствуйте. Появилось задние проанализировать Android приложение на отсылаемые - принимаемые данные. Сделать это нужно с помощью Charles proxy.
Делаю это с помощью эмулятора Android Studio.
Открыл эмулятор с помощью команды в терминале:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_24 -http-proxy ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх:8888
```

Добавил SSL сертификат в эмулятор. В настройках эмулятора в APN указываю и IP и Port указанный в Charles...

При расшифровке трафика каждая папка подписывается с портом 443.
Например:

> https://site.com:443
>
> https://example.com:443

и т.п.
Во вкладке Notes пишет: 
SSL Proxying not enabled for this host: enable in Proxy Settings, SSL locations

Я видел такую же проблему где-то. Там решением было добавить в SSL Locations

> Host:
>   * Port: 443

Также я пробовал добавить

> Host:
>   * Port:
>   *

Но при этом интернет вообще перестает работать на эмуляторе.
Я устанавливал другую версию Charles... Не помогло!
Что еще можно посмотреть?